# youtube right click menu

Tags: youtube, contextmenu, right-click

I just logged into youtube and found out that they replaced my context right click menu with their own. If I want to use regular one, I have to double click my right mouse button. 
Is there any way to turn that off? I just want my old regular right click context menu

Comment: Not sure how can anyone be able to help you, but, my best guess is: try check the options in your channel. Enter this URL `https://www.youtube.com/channel/<CHANNEL_ID>?disable_polymer=true` where `CHANNEL_ID` is your channel id and customize your channel settings.